# How to export Java project to runnable jar with resources?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, resources

I would like to ask how to properly export Java project in IntelliJ IDEA to runnable jar file? My attempt exporting: Project Structure -> Artifacts -> "+" -> Javafx Application -> From module 'xyz', in tab "JavaFX" I write application class and change "Native bundle" to "all". After that I am building project.

Structure:

```
project  
├── out  
│    └── ...  
├── src (marked as root folder)  
│    └── sample  
│         ├── resources (marked as resources folder)  
│         |   └──some txt file  
│         ├── Main.java  
│         ├── Controller.java  
│         └── layout.fxml
```

In main java I am trying to get txt file using
`new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt").getFile())`
While compilinf project in IDE everything is OK, but after exporting and running jar file the program can't find txt file. The same problem is when the resources folder is inside in "project" (the same level as src folder).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting the project as is into a jar file the input file will be in the resources folder.

Try changing the code to something like

`new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/file.txt").getFile())`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :/ Do you have any others solutions?

Comment: It could be very well in the location “src/sample/resources/file.txt” inside the jar. You could give that a try. If nothing works I will inspect the contents of the jar and give the path accordingly.